# Hide a div after selecting a radio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on the following codes where I want the input `number` to appear only when the radio `Mobile Money` is selected.

**Script:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('id') == 'mobilemoney') {
      $('#mobilemoneynumber').show();
    } else {
      $('#mobilemoneynumber').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

**Html:**

```
<form class="form-basic" method="post" action="#">
  <div class="form-row">
    <label><span>Select one</span></label>
    <div class="form-radio-buttons">
      <div>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="radio" id="mobilemoney">
          <span>Mobile Money</span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="radio">
          <span>Cash on delivery</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>Number</span>
      <input type="text" id="mobilemoneynumber" name="mobilemoneynumber">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <button type="submit">Submit Form</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

By default when the page is displayed only the input `number` is displayed and I want it to be displayed by default.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add value to both radio:

```
<input  type="radio" name="radio" value="mobilemoney">
<input type="radio" name="radio"  value="cash">
```

Jquery:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
    if($(this).val() == 'mobilemoney') {
        $('#mobilemoneynumber').show();           
    }
    else {
        $('#mobilemoneynumber').hide();   
    }
});
```

Comment: By default, the input `#mobilemoneynumber` is displayed. Is there any way for me to hide it ?

Comment: yes add style="display:none"; in that inputbox and by default set Cash on delivery radio button checked

Answer (score 1):

`Radio` is wrapped in the element `'form-row'`. Which is the previous element of the parent of `input` element.

```
 $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
   if ($(this).attr('id') == 'mobilemoney') {
     $(this).closest(".form-row").next().show();
   } else {
     $(this).closest(".form-row").next().hide();
   }
 });
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/4349/)

`closest(".form-row")` will return the parent element which has the classname `form-row`